# Return sum of matching rows as a separate field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL query that will give me field C as the sum of field B for each unique row in field A. So for X, field B has 10 and 35, therefore field C would should 45 for both rows of X.

I need a query that will return the entire result as one "dataset" like below (instead of a query that just gives me field C). I think maybe I would need 2 queries? One to grab A and B results and then a 2nd query to select from results and SUM(*expression*) for field C?

[image]

Comment: a window function with Partition By A and SUM B would work I think

Comment: If you want to pass you gotta go to class. Don't skip and then dump homework problems here. Also see [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Comment: I know it sounds like a homework question when I was writing the question but I can assure you it's not. Real world problem here. I just wrote it in simpler terms to make the problem more visible instead of writing a bunch of SQL. I also wrote a suggestion to solving the problem, albeit vague but still a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a window function `SUM()OVER()` or a `SUM()` within a subquery like

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  A VARCHAR(10),
  B INT
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('X', 10),
('Y', 15),
('Z', 40),
('X', 35),
('Y', 10);

SELECT *,
       (SELECT SUM(B) FROM T WHERE A = TT.A) C,
       SUM(B) OVER(PARTITION BY A) AnotherC
FROM T TT;
```

**[Here is a live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b21fdf8f38b5940f8aec38ff8b6fb84)**

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Sami posted while I was doing my copy/paste :) but here's a similar solution:

```
Declare @test Table
    (
        a   varchar(10), 
        b   int
    )

Insert Into @test (a, b) Values ('X', 10);
Insert Into @test (a, b) Values ('Y', 15);
Insert Into @test (a, b) Values ('Z', 40);
Insert Into @test (a, b) Values ('X', 35);
Insert Into @test (a, b) Values ('Y', 10);

Select      t.a, t.b, (Select sum(sq.b) From @test sq Where sq.a = t.a) as c
From        @test t
```

Answer (score 2):

The below given query is enough.

```
select A,B, SUM(B) OVER(PARTITION BY A) AS C FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Like I see that 13 hours before?

Comment: What purpose does a duplicate answer serve ?